# MongoDB Overflow sort stage on text search

Tags: mongodb, sorting, text

Using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) v2.6, it's not uncommon that if one is sorting a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) from a large result set to get an [overflow](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14142).

```
cursor = db.collection.find( { "key" : "value" } )
cursor.sort( { "rank" : 1 } )  // This can blow up
```

The error looks much like:

> **Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33598393 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes**

The solution, in this case, is to [provide an index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex) for the sort criteria, not just the key.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "rank" : 1 } )  // ascending
```

And this works beautifully.

---

**I'm running into this problem in a different place, a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).**  Following the directions in the MongoDB Manual on [text index creation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/), I've done precisely this:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
   { "$**": "text" },
   { name: "TextIndex" }
)
```

And, this has created a text index across all fields on all my [ExtendedJSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) objects in the collection.

Searching works perfectly.

```
cursor = db.collection.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "NEEDLE" } } )
cursor.count()                      // w00t!  records that have NEEDLE in them
```

However, **attempting to do the same sort that worked before now fails**, even if an index exists for the sort field:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "rank" : 1 } )  
cursor = db.collection.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "NEEDLE" } } )
cursor.sort( { "rank" : 1 } )      // This blows up with the same error message
```

> **Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33598393 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes**

*Here's the weird part.*

Iterating over the cursor *without* performing the sort works fine, that's how I get count above.  I can even step through the cursor and see the *unordered* results, so the text search clearly works.

However, *omitting* the text search cause the sort to work just fine; this makes me think it isn't quantity based, though I know it's really just using the sort key's index.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "rank" : 1 } )  
cursor = db.collection.find( )     // Get absolutely everything
cursor.sort( { "rank" : 1 } )      // Well, sort now works again... hmm....
```

**Just as I had to "help" Mongo by providing an index so it could sort without bring all the records into memory, how does one accomplish this for text indexes?**

*Unfortuantely, I can't get an [explain plan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) as it too yields the same error.  If I do it on the results of the [.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.find/) sans [.sort()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/), it shows the obvious -- a full scan on the data, with no `IndexBounds` field.*

---

ADDENDUM: It's not one field, but all fields, that I'm trying to text index -- hence the `"$**"`.  As an experiment, I manually did `.ensureIndex(...)` on all fields, hoping this would help with the sort. But remember, I'm not trying to sort the text fields -- merely using that as a mechanism to get a collection of JSON objects that matched the search criteria. Once I have that collection, and I do get that collection, I'm trying to sort it by the `rank` field, which already does have an index and works in the other scenarios.

Comment: In the example above, I'm not trying ever to get the rank of the text search, rather just use text search to select records (grab a subset); the records themselves have an independent rank field associated with them, so the goal is to sort the returned subset by that value -- hence the code above.

Comment: While both are indexes, a text index and a "normal" index are totally different in how they actually function (and the underlying data structure). A text index can't help you sort the values of the text field like a "normal" index. Create a "normal" index on the text field and use that to sort. However, it seems a little funky to sort on the same fields you'd use text search on, unless they are just titles or something.

Comment: @wdberkeley: (See the addendum above.)  It isn't a single text field [above "the text field"], but all fields "$**" [as docs say]. While full-text search is working, it's the returned collection I can't sort, by my preexisting "rank" field that does have an index, although I can sort by it for other queries just fine. I'm hoping I'm just misunderstanding what you're recommending so I have a path to try. Can you describe what you mean by 'Create a "normal" index on the text field and use that to sort.'?  I've got multiple fields to search within and a single field to sort by. Much appreciated.

Comment: OK. I see what is going on. The text index is preventing you from using the index on rank to do the sort. Then MongoDB tries to sort in memory on rank, but hits the memory limit for doing so. I don't think there is a way around this other than to sort it yourself or restrict the number of results to a sortable number. I'll let you know if I think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13272994/2440358) will help you.

To sum it up: you should not call ensureIndex in the middle of your program, but let Mongoose call it for you. Just add the flag `index: true`in your Schema to the field you want to use for sorting. In your case it should be fine to add it to rank and to name. At least this is working for me in my project.

Example:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
   ...
   normalText : String,
   rank : { type: Number, index: true},
   name : { type: String, index: true }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Stefan!  As an FYI, just to help put your mind at ease, the above example was for the mongo> shell for the case of illustrating the problem.  I concur, don't put the ensureIndex within a program.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help.
Try adding the code like this.
This is for sorting rank.
*$cursor = $cursor.sort({ "rank" : 1 }));*
But you need to sort the $text,
tryout this,
*$cursor = $cursor->sort({ "text" : 1 });*

Thanks.